# Hi, I hope someone could help me with this basic question. This is about grouping a vector into pairs and inpairs with R for a rnorm vector

Tags: r, vector

Basically I created the following vector using `x <- rnorm(100,0,1)`.
I would like to group the pairs into vector `p` and impairs into vector `i`, could someone help me, thanks?

Comment: I suspect you mean odd and even numbers (paro and imparo in Spanish)? `rnorm(100,0,1)` generates a vector of 100 normally distributed random numbers with mean 0 and standard deviation 1, so grouping into even and odd is not possible.

Comment: That is right, odd and even number. I was asked to create a vector x<-rnorm (100,0,1), then to group the values from this vector into two separate vectors, one for odd number positions and one for even numbers positions on the vector. Let's say I have the following vector X<- (2,3,4,7,9,15,10). How could I set two separate vectors listing the positions of vector (x) that are odd numbers and those that are even number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create `sample()` data with randomly sampling 10 integers (i.e. whole numbers, that can be written without a fractional component) between 0 and 100 and store it in vector `x`.

```
set.seed(1)             # make it retroducible
x <- sample(1:100, 10)

> x
 [1] 68 39  1 34 87 43 14 82 59 51
```

Now let's test if the elements of vector `x` are devisible by 2 (stored to vector `even`) or indevisible by 2 (stored to vector `odd`).

```
odd <- x[which(x %% 2 != 0)]
even <- x[which(x %% 2 == 0)]

> odd
[1] 39  1 87 43 59 51

> even
[1] 68 34 14 82
```

Next, let's create a vector `y` containing 10 normally distributed normal numbers (with mean 0 and standard deviation 0, as in your example).

```
set.seed(1)             # make it retroducible
y <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)

> y
[1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684  0.4874291  0.7383247  0.5757814 -0.3053884
```

Again, let's test whether the elements of `y` are devisible by 2.

```
indevisible_by_two <- y[which(y %% 2 != 0)]
devisible_by_two <- y[which(y %% 2 == 0)]

> indevisible_by_two
 [1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684  0.4874291  0.7383247  0.5757814 -0.3053884

> devisible_by_two
numeric(0)
```

However, this only tells us that the elements of vector y are not devisible by 2 and does not mean that they are even or odd. Since `rnorm()` doesn't lead to integers, the attributes of odd and even do not apply.

Therefore, your initial question to split `x <- rnorm(100,0,1)` into odd and even numbers is mathematically impossible.